# How to use Trim in sql case

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
select
distinct ca.CASE_KEY,
ca.priority,
ca.lock_flag,
ca.alternate_case_id as ALTERNATIVE_CASE_ID,
ca.case_identifier as case_identifier

from cases ca
```

The above query returns alternate_case_id as 'null' because there is a string 'null' in db.

the client wants to see nothing if it is null. How can I use ***sql case along with Trim*** so that this bug will work for data like '  null'. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if the string was actually `NULL`, or contained the text `'null'`... so I handled both cases...

```
select
distinct ca.CASE_KEY,
ca.priority,
ca.lock_flag,
nvl(NULLIF(ca.alternate_case_id, 'null'), '') as ALTERNATIVE_CASE_ID,
ca.case_identifier as case_identifier
from cases ca
```

Comment: Nice, I was going to ask the OP if they are absolutely sure that it's a string 'null' or a real NULL.

Comment: this does not work for '    null'  (just in case there are widespaces in data) so can you please show me how can I use trim function here?

Comment: It's a string 'null'  (bad data)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
select
distinct ca.CASE_KEY,
ca.priority,
ca.lock_flag,
CASE trim(ca.alternate_case_id)
  WHEN 'null' THEN ''
  ELSE ca.alternate_case_id
END AS ALTERNATIVE_CASE_ID,
ca.case_identifier as case_identifier

from cases ca
```

[plsql trim()](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trim.php)
[Case Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(alternate_case_ID,'null','')
```

though you should ask why a `NULL` string is a is a stored value in the first place...

you could update all fields that have `null` string to the actual `NULL` value.

Lastly,

Are you SURE the `null` string is being displayed and it's not just a feature of the tools your using to display `"NULL"`

Where are they seeing `"NULL"` in a webpage? report? Form, SQL Developer (which by default shows `(null)` when a `null` value is encountered..

Comment: this does not work for ' null' (just in case there are widespaces in data) so can you please show me how can I use trim function here?
 
It's a string 'null' (bad data)

Comment: The 'null' is manually entered as an answer to an alternateCaseid parameter of my company's application software as I cannot make a case until I give that parameter some value. Hence it was showing that null string in the result set on querying the db. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out  replace(trim(alternate_case_ID), 'null','') would work as well. I didn't see the preceding spaces originally!